# Changing color of a specific object in an image using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, colors, picker

I want to change the color of sofa in the given image:

[image]

Background remains same, only color of the sofa need to be changed. I have tried with masking technique but couldn't get the needed color. I am giving sample color.

[image]

Please, let me know if there are any easy techniques to customise the color of sofa.

I have already tried by changing the hue. I am not able to get the needed color by changing the hue using openCV library. If that is possible using CSS and Javascript, that is also fine.

Thanks in advance.

FYI Code is below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
 
image = cv2.imread('/content/bluesofa.jpg')
cv2_imshow(image)
 
result = image.copy()
 
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 
# lower boundary Blue color range values; Hue (100 - 110)
lower1 = np.array([90, 100, 20])
upper1 = np.array([100, 255, 255])
 
# upper boundary Blue color range values; Hue (120 - 130)
lower2 = np.array([100,100,20])
upper2 = np.array([120,255,255])
 
lower_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower1, upper1)
upper_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower2, upper2)
 
full_mask = lower_mask + upper_mask;
 
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=full_mask)
 
cv2_imshow(full_mask)
cv2.imwrite('masked_object.jpg',result)

img= cv2.imread('/content/masked_object.jpg')

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# extract the hue channel from the hsv image
hue = img_hsv[:,:,0]

# increment the hue values by 60(random number,could be any number)
hue = hue  + 60


# if pixel values become > 180, subtract 180 
cond_h = hue[:, :] > 180
hue[cond_h] = hue[cond_h] - 180

# assign the modified hue channel to hsv image

img_hsv[:,:,0] = hue


im = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

result = cv2.bitwise_or(original_img,im)

cv2_imshow(result)
```

Comment: Please share you code that explains how far you got while trying to change the hue and why the results didn't meet your expectations!

Comment: Thank you for you response, I have added the code.Please go thru it

Comment: Does it have to be OpenCV to do this ? There are plenty free Photoediting-Programs that can handle this easily by hand. (Paint.NET, Gimp,...)

Comment: I agree there are plenty of photoediting editors like photoshop, paint.net , etc, but trying with opencv seemed to be little challenging, so trying  for it. OpenCV has got  many image processing functions but I am failing to achieve this trivial task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example on how you can modify hue, saturation and value of a masked object:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('bluesofa.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = np.array([90, 100, 20])
upper = np.array([120, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
h = np.mod(h + 170, 180)
s = np.clip(s - 100, 0, 255)
v = np.clip(v + 40, 0, 255)
hsv = cv2.merge([h, s, v])

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

result = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=inv_mask), cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, bgr, mask=mask))

cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", result)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Markus, I would like to know  how do you arrive at the values of (170,100,40) for updating h,s,v in the above code.

Comment: Well, I simply tried. If you want to do it automatically, I think you will need some reference point P1 from the blue sofa and some reference point from the image with the destination colour and calculate the difference in HSV space.

Comment: I have tried with the centre point of the image  as well as taking centre point  of the destination color image. with that difference I was not getting these values.So I was wondering how you got them. Have to find a way to get those values.

Comment: If you look closer to the images you see that they have a texture with different colours. Perhaps you can use the mean value of a small region?

Comment: It seems very challenging to generate values automatically, if I alter only hue, I am not getting the required color, tweaking s and v values I am loosing the texture, getting exact values of target color with texture is really tough. Appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: @Priya KS You can try with a new question here on Stackoverflow. But keep in mind that you can only expect help here if you come with your own idea and a very specific, reproducible problem.